# while loop not working as expected in c

Tags: c, loops, do-while

I am under a situation in c language where I have structure as below:

```
struct afreq
{
  unsigned char sym;  
  int freq;           
  short int left,right;     
};
struct afreq data[512] ;
```

after compilation of the code written it forms this type of structure:

```
[a 0 0 0]
[b 1 0 0]
[z 1 b a]
[c 2 0 0]
[d 3 0 0]
[z 3 c z]
[e 4 0 0]
[z 6 z d]
[z 10 z e]
```

Were the first element is "sym" second is "freq" and third is "left" and fourth is "right".

Now what I have to do is:

Starting from the last element (which is [z 10 z e]) i have to go to all those element whose "left" and "right" both are zero. I also have to count their distance from the right most element(in terms of number of "zero", I mean suppose if we see the structure above, we have left=right="0" at sym="e" so the distance will be "00" , because it's 3 elements far from the right most element).

So the output must be like this:

```
e= 00
d= 000
c= 0000
b= 00000
a= 000000
```

My code for to implement it is as below (which is not working):

```
    i=dataSize-1; //you can see the output below to know it's value, which is exactly
//corresponding to the element matrix i have taken above at starting.
    printf("before i:%d\n");
    do{
      char temp[30];
       strcpy(temp, var);
        strcat(temp, "0");
        printf("\ntemp: %s   ", temp);
        printf("sym :%c  \n", data[i].sym );
        printf("Valuse of i:%d\n",i);
        i=i-1;

    } while(data[i].left==0 && data[i].right==0);
```

The output corresponding to it is (which is not expected):

```
    [a 0 0 0]  [b 1 0 0]  [z 1 b a]  [c 2 0 0]  [d 3 0 0]  [z 3 c z]  [e 4 0 0]  [z 6 z d]  [z 10 z e]  

data size 9
before i:2 
temp: 0
sym :z  //and it prints the last element whereas it's 
left and right child are not zero
Valuse of i:8
```

Could any one please explain how should I change my code to get the desire output? (I am a beginner programmer)

Comment: First of all you should get rid of the `break`-statement, since it prevents, that your `do while`-loop will be executed more than once!

Comment: @Toby  
i removed the break and output is still same , but why it enter in the first element even we don't have left=right=0 there . we can see that for the first index we have [z 10 z e] not [z 10 0 0]

Comment: Please clarify what your code should output. I do not understand the logic behind what you should get for each symbol.

Comment: @WernerHenze I have written my full code for you, please see the do-while loop part, when you run it please take an Input.txt file at sole argument which contains a string abcde, my code will read that.thanks

Comment: You write that your code is not correct. To understand why it is not correct, we must understand what the code shall do and then we can take a look at the code and check why it does not do what you want. Just giving the code without an understandable specification does not help.

Comment: @WernerHenze thanks for trying to help me, I have achieved it using if condition inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `break`!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: i removed the break and output is still same , but why it enter in the first element even we don't have left=right=0 there.we can see that for the first index we have [z 10 z e] not [z 10 0 0] .

Answer (score 0):

Well I can only guess what you want to do (sorry, but I have a hard time understanding your question):

I assume you only want to print the elements which have the value `0` in the fields `left` and `right`. 
What you`re actually doing is, that you`re checking this condition in your `while`-loop, which will cause it to break after the first iteration.
This is because in your first iteration you start with index `i=9` - Then you print out the data for `i` (no matter if it's the data you want or not). Then you check if the data (`left` and `right`) tomatch `0` in the condition of your `while`-loop. Since `data[i]` = `data[9]` it will see that `left!=0` and `right!=0`, which will cause your loop to break.

What you have to do is: Let the loop iterate over all elements from your array, and check inside the loop for your data.

Here some code to explain:

```
i = dataSize-1;   // Initialize your index
do
{
    if((data[i].left==0) && (data[i].right==0))  // Check for your data in left and right
   {
         // Print your data or do whatever you want to do 
   }
   i--; // i = i-1;
} while(i>=0)  // Do this for every index of your array
```

This way you make sure that you check every single one of your elements. Also I would use a `for`-loop instead of a `do-while`, but that's a matter of taste.

I hope this helps you, otherwise try to elaborate your question a bit more!

Comment: I just tried to do what you have asked me to do: i=dataSize-1;
printf("before i:%d\n",i);

do{
if(data[i].left=='0' && data[i].right=='0')
{
  char temp[30];
   strcpy(temp, var);
    strcat(temp, "0");
    printf("\ntemp: %s   ", temp);
 printf("sym :%c  \n", data[i].sym );
 printf("Valuse of i:%d\n",i);
    i=i-1;
 }
 //break;
} while(i>=0);

Comment: but the output get stuck (it makes me feel like any infinite condition is going on):  the data read from file are as follows :
[a 0  0 0] [b 1  0 0] [c 2  0 0] [d 3  0 0] [e 4  0 0] 
 It is in a manner   : Symbol  Frequency  Left Son  Right Son


data size 5
[a 0 0 0]  [b 1 0 0]  [z 1 b a]  [c 2 0 0]  [d 3 0 0]  [z 3 c z]  [e 4 0 0]  [z 6 z d]  [z 10 z e]  
data size 9
before i:8  NOT TUNNING AFTER IT..JUST STOPPED HERE